# How to apply jelly bean apps themes for gingerbread apps?

Tags: android, styles, android-2.3-gingerbread, app-themes

In my new app, I want to use a common theme for jelly bean, ics and gingerbread phones. 
That is, my app should not look different in different platforms.

I have seen some app like 'fancy' which is using jelly bean like theme in gingerbread also.

I'm new to android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the Holo theme using the [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) library. I use it in all my apps, and it works very well.

You have to add it as a library project to use it. If you use Git, you can add it as a submodule.

Comment: @VishalVijay Glad you got it. Please accept the answer if it helped.